# When did PIE people split into subject-verb-object -- SVO and SOV peoples?

Tags: proto-indo-european

Given that PIE people have present-day descendants in India to Europe, they have divided so starkly: in the given map, most languages from India to middle east upto east Europe are SOV, whereas most in west Europe are SVO.

How did this parent population separate into two? How did they evolve to be distinct?

I used http://wals.info/feature/81A#3/43.20/67.76 as a map reference.

Comment: Linguistics would be a better cite also because you may need to evaluate the degree of dominancy of the word order in these languages. Its unlikely that the split happen overnight, and the degree of dominancy of SVO over SOV may help to estimate when particular languages started to show a preference. I cannot speak of many languages, but just comparing fairly rigid English with very flexible Russian is enough to see that word order preference is not equally honored among PIE languages.

Comment: Are you asking about Indo-European? If so, why do you mention Georgian?

Comment: @fdb, PIE as in Proto Indo-Europian. And Georgian was a example more familiar to me, over say Adyghe

Comment: Neither Georgian nor Adyghe (Circassian) are Indo-European. That being said, most IE languages have free word order, i.e., word order is determined by topic-focus articulation (or, if you so wish, information structure).

Comment: @Atamiri: agreeing with you not am I. Free word order IE languages not all have. Otherwise stumbling on my comment's wording not would you.

Comment: Word order is a property of languages, not (ever) of peoples.

Comment: @Michael Do you know what "most" means in English?

Comment: Something's fishy about the map. It lists Russian as SVO, but says Belarussian "has no dominant order", when in fact Russian and Belarussian grammars are almost identical. I speak Russian and studied Belarussian and I failed to see any difference between the languages in choosing word order.

Comment: Following the theses of Stampe & Donegan about the relation between accent and word order, one could expect a correlation with changes in accent or affixation.  See Donegan, Patricia J. & David Stampe (1983). Rhythm and the holistic organization of language structure. In J. F. Richardson et al. (eds.), Papers from the Parasession on the Interplay of Phonology, Morphology and Syntax, 337-353. Chicago: CLS.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to know that many of the languages tagged on the map as SVO are not actually SVO and that not all correctly tagged languages share the same history with respect to word order. For example, the Romance languages derived from an SOV order, whereas English derived from a V2 order. If I were you I would forget about that map as soon as possible.

Comment: A very good point. This is a general problem with lists or maps compiled from books by different authors using different methodologies.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know enough about linguistics to be an expert on that exact linguistic difference. However, the map you supplied looks quite similar to the modern separation between the Indo-Iranian branch of Indo-European and the rest. It is believed that [Indo-Iranian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-Iranian_language) goes back to about the 3rd Millenium, BC. Their separate recorded history starts around the 9th century BC, when they (and their invention, the chariot) [invaded the Iranian plateau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medes). From there some of them turned east and invaded India as well. Presumably this cut them off a bit from the rest of their Indo-European compatriots up on the western Eurasian Steppe, and already "migrating" into Europe.

Note that a lot of the Germanic languages (but not English), according to that map have no dominant order.

Comment: The list at the bottom of the link gives English as SVO.

Comment: @fdb - Clarified. I wasn't sure about English (hadn't found its dot), which is why I'd phrased that sentence in such an awkward way. English has a rather unique history among Germanic languages, so I'm not surprised. It would be interesting to know when this happened. Perhaps a good question idea for someone.

Answer (score -1):

All branches show in their most ancient form either SOV order or its traces. That said, the PIE had SOV word order as the default(unmarked) but being a highly inflective language its word order was mostly free.

Comment: Branches, as in individual languages? And is PIE as well-understood as say, ancient Greek?

Comment: @aitchnyu PIE is understood less than ancient Greek, but there are enough indications that it had generally free word order with SOV as default.

Comment: Ancient IE languages like Vedic, Avestan, Greek have a very free word order, not SOV.

Comment: @fdb Homeric Greek was more SOV, but since the Hellenistic period Greek has been more SVO.

Comment: @fdb A language may have a free word order but still have one it defauls to. Russian, for example, generally defaults to SVO, however a particular sentence can be VSO, SOV or even OSV depending on several factors.

Comment: Any statistics for Greek? And what about Vedic and Avestan?

Comment: @fdb: No statistics. Nobody was counting. All we have is some writing that survived. Not that much. And Pāṇini's grammar, which is not sociolinguistically oriented. As for the OQ, SVO and SOV are not "peoples" and don't define any branch of Indo-European. They just happen to be common enough developments (along with VSO, like Celtic) to mention, like palatalization or umlaut.

Comment: @fdb always that hatred for word order :) Russian is a good example of free worder but still a default. What reason do we have not to assume that for ancient IE languages?

Comment: I don't think there is any reason to assume default SOV for Classical Greek at least (not sure about Homer). Some scholars in fact assume SVO instead (e.g. Agbayani and Golston). In my own opinion, Classical Greek  had nothing that could be called a default constituent order.